# What is the difference between 俯卧撑 and 伏地挺身?

Tags: difference

Both 俯卧撑 (fǔwòchēng) and 伏地挺身 (fúdìtǐngshēn) apparently mean "pushup" [according to MDBG](http://www.mdbg.net/chindict/chindict.php?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=pushups). Google Images doesn't give me a clue as to how these terms are different. Are they exactly the same? Are they regional variations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

俯卧撑 is more commonly used in Mainland Chinese Mandarin, 伏地挺身 in Taiwanese Mandarin.

From Baidu Baike [俯卧撑](http://baike.baidu.com/subview/151130/5402681.htm)

> 俯卧撑（英文：push-up；Press-up。中国大陆称作俯卧撑，中国台湾地区称作伏地挺身，港澳地区称作掌上压）

Also, 俯卧撑 gives more results, probably this the preferred expression.

---

If you search for both expressions on TW domains (with `site:tw [expression]`) on Google, 伏地挺身 gives roughly 4 times more results than 俯卧撑. On PRC domains (site:cn), the situation is opposite, 俯卧撑 is roughly 10 times more common than 伏地挺身. Of course many Chinese and Taiwanese sites use other domains than .cn and .tw, this is just to illustrate the regional difference on a limited set of websites.

Comment: That's a neat trick with site:cn vs tw

Comment: @trideceth12 Thanks. It's not perfect, however. Many Chinese companies, social websites (from both sides of the Taiwan Strait) use other domains, like .com, .net, .org, etc. Of course, in the case of these it's hard to identify if they are written by Mainlanders or Taiwanese. Using Google's Advanced Search and setting the language to Simplified/Traditional Chinese is probably a better approach: https://www.google.com/advanced_search